# Exception using Amazon s3 Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am attempting to upload a file to s3 using the Java SDK. The code works fine on my Windows 7 machine running jdk1.6.0_26 but when run on the server, Ubuntu Server 10.04 with Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147), I get the following error, which appears to coming from https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AbstractAWSSigner.java:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to calculate a request signature: null Stack trace : com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:71)
com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.signAndBase64Encode(AbstractAWSSigner.java:55)
com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3Signer.sign(S3Signer.java:101)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:234)
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:169)
com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2597)
com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1025)
```

The call to s3:

```
AWSCredentials c = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(c);
String key = station + "/" + file.getName();        
client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, file));
```

I am new to Java and not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Having a good answer to this question would be very helpful to this visitor from the future.  Considering the pervasiveness of AWS (then and now) maybe the community should re-evaluate the extraordinarily narrow interpretation of the applicability of this question to the worldwide audience of the internet.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

My gut is that the JDK/JRE you are using on your server does not have the proper crypo/JCE.  Either install the high crypto pack, or install a new JDK/JRE which includes the proper crypo.

Java Cryptography Extension can be downloaded at the bottom :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the jars here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html, and that didn't seem to do it, still receiving same exact exception.

Comment: Locate java.security on each of the computers you are using.  It should list out the security.providers that you have as well as their preference orders.  Find out what you have in the Windows version that isn't in the linux version.

Comment: The only one in windows not in linux is the  Microsoft Crypto API.

Comment: It turns out this is the exception that occurs when careless developers pass in null for the the access key or secret key parameters.  An argument check sure would have been helpful, perhaps I'll submit a patch.